# Do we need to have device channels to view our SharePoint site on mobile

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am facing issues with mobile view of my SharePoint site. My site works fine in when i disable 'Mobile Browser View' feature but when i disable it , It shows the blank screen on my android phone.**Do we need to have device channels to view our SharePoint 2013 site on mobile** , Or if we just enable 'Mobile Browser View' feature of site collection it starts working on different phones in a mobile view ?

Answer (score 1):

Device Channel uses different master pages according to different devices (mobile or tablets). It works only on specific **[browser Chrome](http://motive.co.nz/glossary/chrome.php)** versions.

My suggestion is to create a single responsive master page & apply it to SharePoint site. It will support in every device whether it is mobile, tablet or desktop.

You do not need to enable 'Mobile Browser View'.

Comment: I created a team site and enable publishing features , and then enabled Mobile browser feature . and when i tried opening it on my android phone it just shows the heading of the site and a blank page . 'Switch to PC view' does not work . isnt it supposed to show complete site with that 'Mobile Browser' feature. @Hardik

Comment: Please all necessary steps here first on this site https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-SharePoint-site-for-mobile-devices-ddf28727-3bfe-4b56-951d-c97204eac475

Comment: Have you checked given link?

Comment: yes @Hardik , I have . But i dont know i followed the same approach and the out of the box way it should have worked , but it doesnt open .